# Java: should the same object be used for synchronization and waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

When waiting and notifying on an object 'x'  assume x.wait() and x.notify() . Should the calls to wait and notify be also synchronized on the same object ? I mean synchronized(x){x.wait} , or is it ok/sensible/wrong to use another object for synchronization I mean synchronized(y){x.wait} .

Comment: synchronized(y){x.wait} won't work. You can try it.

Answer (score 2):

> Should the calls to wait and notify be also synchronized on the same object?

Not only *should* they be synchronized on the same object, they *must* be synchronized on the same object.

In fact, the documentation of [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) and [notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) is quite clear on what will happen if code doesn’t follow that rule:

> **Throws:**
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.